# Why phones battery charges faster when magnetic case is stuck onto a metal?

Tags: battery

Ragarding my previous question [Here.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/761197/why-phones-battery-charges-faster-when-magnetic-case-is-stuck-onto-a-metal)

My phone was at 18% battery. Placed the side of the magnetic case which the behind side of my phone is attached to, on top of a metallic lid.  It took less than 7 minutes for the phone to charge up to 37% which is a little bit less than it usually does (don't have mesures).

--) Being precise

1. I would have to read: phone's OS code, Apps installed code, third parties code.
2. I would have to read: HDL for the phone's hardware system.
3. Create a histogram for each cycle assuming that i have mapped every call correctly ( which i would ).
4. Find information for the materials and the processes the phone is made of.
5. Find information about the materials the case and the lid is made of.
6. Calculate corrotion for the time passed since said phone was bought related to how it was used.
7. Recreate the histogram.
8. Have almost absolute controll of its surrounding environment
   As you can imagine, i do not have the time, knowledge and patience.
   Anyone having what's mentioned in the above sentence, can have a look.
   This may be absolute bullshit (sorry for the language) but it will 100% be no waste of time.

P.S.
It is going to be great! Pika-Chu! Pika, Pika ( Good Luck!)

Comment: I don't think this is a thing.

Answer (score 0):

If the effect is real, it *might* have to do with the metallic lid acting as a heat sink during the charging cycle. This is a testable hypothesis.

Comment: Use the 3 Right hand Rules :D